# Reverse geolocation. Loading api/geocode I get SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'. Parse error

Tags: geocoding, reverse-geocoding

This is​​ a single script.php only to load data.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>TEST</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="location">
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=42.149247222222,24.752305555556&key=My-enabled-key-here">
</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In Mac Safari I get I get `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'. Parse error.

Several data is loaded I see it in Safari debugger starting in:

[image: First part of Safari debugger]

but I cannot use it because of that error message.
In Chrome and Opera I get Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response  with MIME type application/json.
Reading some old questions I added

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com') ?>
```

and then replaced by

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *') ?>
```

as the first line but nothing changed.

From Google side: Key restrictions
-> Application restrictions: none.
-> API restrictions: yes (key is accepted for 4 APIs, one of them is Geocoding API

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are making a [Geocoding web service request](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start) in the **client-side** (front-end) that's why you are getting the Cross-origin blocking error (CORB). Web service requests are meant to be executed **server side**.

Note that if you intend to use Geocoding in client-side, the JavaScript API has a Geocoding Service (which prevents the CORB issue). Please refer to this guide: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding

Hope this helps!

Comment: So you say I have to use node.js https://developers.google.com/maps/web-services/client-library What about `Unexpected token ":". Parse error` ? At this time I am trying `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=mykey&callback=initMap" async defer></script>` and it works okay. initMap is a function to handle geodata